# How to run a test case without opening the browser window?

Tags: java, eclipse, automated-tests, webdriver

I have created a set of test cases using Firefox Driver in Eclipse IDE.

But now I need these test cases to run without opening the browser window.  How can I achieve that?

Presently I am using Firefox Driver Web Driver that runs in Firefox Browser.
Can some one help me with an example?

Comment: **Why** do you need to do this without opening the browser window?

Comment: well this the the need i have been provided with

Comment: If you don't want to use a browser, consider using the HtmlUnitDriver. If you want to use Firefox, you must use the Firefox driver which will require Firefox to run. You simply cannot have it both ways.

Comment: yes i dont wanna use browser.....

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to think about compatibility of different web browser, you could try  Celerity. It could be run automated test script without any browser window.

http://celerity.rubyforge.org/

It is based on JRuby, and is very easy to learn and use.